# Modifying labels for a tukeys HSD plot in R

Tags: r, statistics

Hi there so I'm a beginner at all this and need help modifying my Tukeys y-axis labels as they are all ontop of each other...is there a way?

Please see my code:

```
both<-aov(cowpea.and.wheat$Protein.conc..ug.Protein.g.1.Fwt.~cowpea.and.wheat$Treatment*Species, data=cowpea.and.wheat)
summary(both)
TukeyHSD(both)
par(mar=c(3,10,2,1))
plot(TukeyHSD(both),las=1)
```

image of plot:

[image]

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Could you provide some test data for people to use? Also, would you mind removing your reference to rstudio in your title and tags? R and rstudio are distinct pieces of software and your question is about R.

Comment: Hi I put Rstudio as it is the program I am working from. Also the data itself doesnt matter, its basically just four treatments (2,8,20,24,36) with corresponding protein contents that range in number.

Comment: But it is difficult to provide guidance without a working dataset. One thing to note is that if you blow the graph up to full screen or a full page pdf, the labels will become more visible.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
with(par(mai=c(1,2.5,1,1)),{plot(TukeyHSD(both), las=1,cex.axis=0.4)})

##par(mai=c(1,2.5,1,1)) adjusts the margin

##cex.axis=0.4 adjusts the axis font size relative to graph
```

If you could respond with a graphic (although the question was asked back months) with the above parameters, to see if my proposal is effective.
Greetings and luck!